# Find total size of struct at runtime

Tags: rust

Is there any way to calculate the total stack and heap size of a struct at runtime?

As far as I can tell, [`std::mem::{size_of, size_of_val}`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) only work for stack-allocated values, but a struct might contain heap-allocated buffers, too (e.g. `Vec`).

Answer (score 5):

[Servo](https://github.com/servo/servo) was using the [heapsize](https://crates.io/crates/heapsize) crate to measure the size of heap allocations during program.

You can call the [`heap_size_of`](https://docs.rs/heapsize/0.4.2/heapsize/fn.heap_size_of.html) function to measure the allocated heap size by jemalloc.

Be aware that you can get different results with different allocators.

---

*Regarding Github: "This crate is not maintained and is no longer used by Servo. At the time of writing, Servo uses internal malloc_size_of instead."*

You can either use ***heapsize*** crate or you can check the implementation details of [`malloc_size_of`](https://github.com/servo/servo/tree/faf3a183f3755a9986ec4379abadf3523bd8b3c0/components/malloc_size_of) as well